# In welchen Situationen wird "Alles Gute" verwendet?

Tags: usage, expression

Manchmal benutzte oder hörte ich es bei Geburtstagswünschen, Krankheit oder mutmachend, freundlich Aufwiedersehen sagend.

Kann man *Alles Gute* in diesen verschiedenen Kontexten anwenden oder nur bei bestimmten?

Comment: *Alles Gute* is short for *Ich wünsche dir alles Gute* (*I wish you all the best*) and can be used in all contexts where you want to express sympathy. When used to say goodbye, it means *farewell*.

Comment: Diese verschiedenen Kontexte sind doch gerade von Dir bestimmt worden - wo ist der Gegensatz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Alles Gute* ist eine Aussage, die für viele Situationen angewendet werden kann. Hier sind einige Beispiele:

> Alles Gute zum Geburtstag.
>   Alles Gute zum Hochzeitstag.
>   Alles Gute zum Führerschein.

Alles Gute ist eine Redewendung, die Glück und Gutes wünschen soll. Ich wünsche dir alles Gute (der Welt) / Glück (der Welt) für eine bestimmte Sache.

Also: wann immer du jemandem zu etwas gratulieren möchtest, kannst du alles Gute sagen. Eher selten kann man es aber auch verwenden, um zu etwas zu ermutigen oder zu ermuntern: „Alles Gute für die Untersuchung gleich!“, oder „Alles Gute für die Prüfung! Du schaffst das schon!“

Comment: Thanks for these explanations, but this is not entirely clear to me. The first three examples you give seem to imply that "alles Gute" is used to wish for the best for the future, but then the third paragraph says the opposite. For instance, if I say "alles Gute zum Führerschein", is it for someone who WILL try the driving test in the future, or for someone who HAS ALREADY got the driving license ?

Comment: It is not exactly to wish the best in the future, though you can use it that way. You could even say "Alles Gute für die Zukunft." Which translates to "All the best for the future." It is just a general felicitation... you could also say "Alles Gute zum Geburtstag" or All the best for your birthday. "Alles Gute zum Führerschein" here just means "Congrats to your license." Or "All the best for your License". You can use it most of the time, when congrats are due: "Alles Gute zum neuen Job" or "All the best for your new job (you just started or will be starting soon)".

Comment: Danke für die Erklärung!

Answer (score 2):

Es kann aber auch als Abschied gemeint sein, anstelle der klassischen Abschiedsworte.

Statt "Tschüss" oder "Pass auf Dich auf" kann man auch "Alles Gute" sagen.